# Maven POM Inheritance or Aggregation or Dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jenkins, multi-module

- Our team develops around 5  web apps every year for various
  departments in our company.
- Applications are not related, they have their own app server, database and  DB based users, no single sign-on servers or common database.
- Every new project, we recreate(copy/paste from a previous project)
  Java & Javascript's common codes like user management, Menu
  Management, code description, security etc
- Look and feel is changed as per the requirement.
- Now we created a util project which has some common
  methods (like  email, phone number  validators, Date Time utils,
  Date Serializer etc)
- New projects use util project as a dependency.
- When we identify a need for new util method, we add it to the util
  project and release a new version.(util project with its own life
  cycle). other projects can upgrade to new version of util if required.

Our technology stack is  Spring boot - spring MVC, security, data-JPA & Angular JS  & Thymeleaf

Now I want to avoid recreating the common stuff (user, menu code description etc) for each project.

I don't have practical knowledge of multimodule maven projects, so unable to decide, what is the best practice.

Here are the options?

- Creating parent project(with user, menu's service, repositories, entity class etc)  and inherit into other projects. (only parent pom or  parent project with classes)
- Create common stuff as one module and aggregate.(how to manage lifecycle?)
- Create common stuff as an independent maven project with its own
  lifecycle and use it as a dependency.(What will happen to client-side scripts)

Would like to know the best practice.

Comment: I suggest you to create a jar file for your util project and include the jar when ever it needed

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan we are already doing that for common utility classes/methods, My question is should I add the user, menu classes also into  its own project ( core jar project) or should I do some inheritance or multimodule. because this common classes will need its own dependencies like spring data, security, hibernate , so how to manage the dependencies.,

Answer (score 0):

First rule of shared libraries - do not create shared libraries. At some point in every organization someone tries to share the code that they duplicate from project to project. And after couple of years it becomes impossible to maintain.

Unless you can create a high-quality library that's (at least theoretically) possible to open source - you won't do any good for your company.

If you do want to create a high-quality reusable library, then here are some rules:

- A lib or a set of connected libs usually reside in separate projects (repositories).
- A lib shouldn't be project-specific or company-specific, it needs to be pretty generic so that people from other organizations *theoretically* could use it
- It should look the same way as open source libraries - you just include it as yet another dependency.
- They cannot cover features from top (UI) to bottom (back end entities). Each library has its own small task to accomplish. If it's a UI component - then it's a re-usable NPM package, if it's a Java utility for common calculation - then it should be that utility and that's it. Inter-connection between multiple packages should be very limited (if any).

  - If you *do* want to share a top-to-bottom functionality, think about creating a standalone application and possibility for service-to-service communication, iframes, etc.
- No Spring contexts should be included into reusable libraries. Spring is a part of each standalone application and cannot be shared.

So think twice before creating a shared lib and be prepared to spend *a lot* of time maintaining it.

Comment: This answer provides an insight into what will happen with shared libraries and got me thinking if shared libraries are necessary  in small organization or team